# Recover an AES encrypted file password when I have the original file

Tags: encryption

If someone has both the encrypted file and the original file - Is there a way to know what was the secret used to encrypt the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is a block cipher that is not susceptible to a [Known-plantext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). Brute force is your only option.