# Recovering AES encryption key with both encrypted and unencrypted file at hand

Tags: security, encryption, aes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover an AES encrypted file password when I have the original file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296259/recover-an-aes-encrypted-file-password-when-i-have-the-original-file)

Basically the title already is the question. There are about twenty .doc files that I would like to decrypt, they are encrypted with MyWinLocker, which means AES as far as I know. And now I have an unencrypted copy of one of the encrypted files and would like to know if there exists a way of using the pair of files to get an decryption key that I could use on the others, or if possible, find the password used.

Comment: This is called a *known plaintext* attack. AES is resilient to such a class of attack.

Answer (score 1):

I would say NO. And that is because cryptographic algorithms has to be resilient to attacks such as: [Known plaintext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) and [Choosen ciphertext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack)